# Missing attachments from specific domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003, outlook-2010

one of our users has problem with receiving PDF attachments from one domain. 
The body of the mail is recieved without any change, but there is no sign of attachments. He has this problem only with PDF attachments, zip, office doc etc. delivers fine.

When same sender forwards the e-mail to another Exchange user, it's delivered just fine, with attachments.

Clients computers are with Win7 64bit/Office2010 Business.
Company mail server runs Windows 2003 SBS, Exchange 2003

Pls help :-)

//and before you ask - yes, they sends the attachment every time :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like the receiver has some program running that is deleting the attachment.  You need to do more debugging - it sounds like you haven't tried nearly enough conditions to come close to pinpointing where the issue is.

Try logging on to a different system (one that has no problems with attachments) under the user's account and see if the attachment is there.  Also, check their mail rules to make sure no rules are deleting attachments or anything.  Check their spam settings, etc...

Also, check the Exchange server logs.

Answer (score 0):

It actually sounds like there is some sort of transport rule preventing certain filetypes from being delivered from one user/domain.

To debug a bit more, have someone else on the sender's domain send the recipient a .pdf, and have the original sender send a .pdf to someone else on the recipient's domain.